# Custom Blog Theme

Tags: theming, nodes

I'm not that experienced with drupal but I know some web design/dev. I have created a mockup using html and css of how I want a blog page to look. How do I make it that when someone adds a new blog post (with title,content and a picture) it gets rendered the way my mockup looks and not the default? How would drupal know to put my blog elements exactly like the mockup depicts?